# Accessing UINavigationController from rootVC Subview (subview loaded from Nib)

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, subview, nib

The main ViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController subclass, and the VC has a subview that is loaded from a nib. The subview is called MenuView, and contains UIButtons that will link to other VCs.

To keep my main ViewController less unruly, I have put all these buttons into a subview that loads from a nib that animates the menu opening and closing.

However, I would like to present other view controllers from these, sometimes "Modally", sometimes "Show". What I have done seems to work, but I just want to know if this is alright, or if I have caused some unwanted effects that I'm unaware of (like a strong reference cycle that would cause a memory leak, or something). Or is there a better way to do this?

Some code:
In MenuView.swift

```
class MenuView: UIView {
    var navigationController = CustomNavigationController()

    func combinedInit(){
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MenuViewXib", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.frame = self.bounds
    }

    @IBAction func optionsAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController.performSegueWithIdentifier("presentOptions", sender: self)
    }
```

In ViewController.swift

```
        menuView.navigationController = self.navigationController as! CustomNavigationController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No, it is not alright to access a view controller from within some view in the hierarchy, because that would break all the [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) rules written.**

---

`UIView` objects are meant to display UI components in the screen and are responsible for drawing and laying out their child views correctly. That's all there is. Nothing more, nothing less.

You should handle those kind of interactions between views and controllers always in the controller in which the view in question actually belong. If you need to send messages from a view to its view controller, you can make use of either the [delegate approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) or [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) class.

If I were in your shoes, I would use a delegate when view needs some information from its view controller. It is more understandable than using notification center as it makes it much easier to keep track of what's going on between. If the view controller needs some information from a view *(in other words, the other way around)*, I'd go with the notification center.

```
protocol MenuViewDelegate: class {
  func menuViewDidClick(menuView: MenuView)
}

class MenuView: UIView {
  var weak delegate: MenuViewDelegate?

  @IBAction func optionsAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.menuViewDidClick(self)
  }
}
```

Let's look at what's going on at the view controller side:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, MenuViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.menuView.delegate = self
  }

  func menuViewDidClick(menuView: MenuView) {
    navigationController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("presentOptions", sender: self)
  }
}
```

---

For more information about communication patterns in iOS, you might want to take a look at this great [article](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/communication-patterns.html) in order to comprehend how they work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking of using a delegate because they're pretty easy to understand. In the case of the delegate, I just write a protocol with a function like presentViewController(segueKey: String), and then put that function in my main viewcontroller, and assign the menuView.delegate to self. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. I've updated my answer so you can see how I'd do using a delegate.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Quick question: Why is it necessary to pass the sender as an argument to the ViewController in the menuViewDidClick method?

Comment: I didn't pass the `sender` in the delegate callback. Just passed the view `self` who let the delegate know it is this view who was clicked. Sure, you don't have to pass anything but it is a good practice to let delegate know what view it is dealing with at that moment.